# return alphabets from array: for loop not working

Tags: php, arrays

**Motive:** I want to get all aplphabets from a-z  using array.

**Progress:** The thing I have tried so far is.

**Code:**

```
    $ap = range('a', 'z');
    $toecho="";
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) 
{
    $ap = $ap[i];
    $toecho .='<a href="/view/'.$ap.'" title="movies starting with letter '.$ap.'">'.$ap.'</a>';
    echo $toecho;
        }
```

But it wont print `/view/a"` ... it just prints `/view/"`

Comment: what is $ap[i]...if array what it contains?

Comment: Your $alphas having A TO Z and you are sing $ap in loop. replace $ap with $alphas

Comment: I did actually firstly I was using this `$ap = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');` then i inserted range.

Comment: But you overwrite the variable `$ap` inside the loop.

Comment: you can try the updated code anywhere like this http://writecodeonline.com/php/ it wo'nt output alphabets.

Comment: See Benjamin's answer, it should work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 errors in same line `$ap = $ap[i];` to `$ap = $alphas[$i];`

[i] -> no constant i
$ap = $ap -> you overried you $ap variable

**Code :**

```
$alphas = range('a', 'z');
$toecho="";

for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) 
{
    $ap = $alphas[$i];
    $toecho .='<a href="/view/'.$ap.'" title="movies starting with letter '.$ap.'">'.$ap.'</a><br />';
}
echo $toecho;
```

**Additional code :**
We can make it better

```
$toecho="";
foreach (range('a', 'k') as $letter) {
    $toecho .='<a href="/view/'.$letter.'" title="movies starting with letter '.$letter.'">'.$letter.'</a><br />';
}
echo $toecho;
```

Answer (score 2):

The code violates KISS principle. Ranges in PHP are iterable themselves:

```
$toecho = '';
foreach(array_slice(range('a', 'z'), 0, 10) as $a) {
  $toecho .= "<a href='/view/${a}' title='starting with ${a}'>${a}</a><br />";
}
echo $toecho;
```

Does what you want in much more readable way. Hope it helps. Note, that if you do not need the break after the last item, you could use join:

```
$toecho = implode('<br>', array_map(function($a) { 
  return "<a href='/view/${a}' title='starting with ${a}'>${a}</a>"; 
}, array_slice(range('a', 'z'), 0, 10)));
echo $toecho;
```

Comment: @Saqueib updated an answer to slice a range. It’s better to try to be as semantically adequate as possible.

Comment: This is actually more SUPERB but stackoverflow allows me to only accept a single answer. But hope it helps someone else in the community.

Comment: It is now more superb. Wish i had the reputation enough to upvote.

Comment: Why array slice ? Change range.
Why ${a} ? no dynamic variable name, use $a.
Really complicated for nothing, check my updated answer

Comment: @BenjaminPoignant You found this notation complicated, I find it clear and self-explaining. You will understand why there is a matter to write `${a}` rather than `$a`. It’s a matter of experience.

Comment: I do not agree with you but I'm not saying you're wrong, we all have our habits.If it s clear for you and IdidntKnewIt that fine

Answer (score 1):

You have overwritten the `$ap` var, here is working

```
$ap = range('a', 'z');

 $toecho="";
 for ($i = 0; $i <= 10; $i++) 
  {
    $a = $ap[$i]; //use a different variable name than array itself
    $toecho .='<a href="/view/'.$a.'" title="movies starting with letter '.$a.'">'.$a.'</a>';
  }

  echo $toecho;
```

Comment: Just missed that [$i].

Comment: @IdidntKnewIt and overwritten the `$ap` in same line

Comment: You put echo in for loop

Comment: That `ap[i];` instead of `ap[$i];` helped the overwriting.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminPoignant No i corrected that myself already. and you already mentioned that in your answer.